# OneNote keyboard shortcut to go to previously viewed page

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-onenote

For example I am in Notebook B and I look at page 1B then I go to notebook C and look at page 1C. Is there a keyboard shortcut to take me back to page 1B in notebook B? In other words, the previous page I viewed?

No relation but similar example in intellij https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441541/keyboard-shortcut-for-jump-to-previous-view-location-navigate-back-forward-in

and sublime text https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996878/how-to-jump-to-previous-and-last-cursor-in-sublime-text-3

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Windows you can navigate to previously-viewed pages with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>.

On MacOS the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to move back and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to move forward again.

This works even if you move between Notebooks while navigating. These and other keyboard shortcuts supported by OneNote are documented in this [Microsoft Office support article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-onenote-for-windows-44b8b3f4-c274-4bcc-a089-e80fdcc87950).

Comment: If anyone else ends up here for a back button keyboard shortcut for OneNote on Mac, this answer inspired me to try some different shortcuts out and I found it.  For Mac it is Ctrl+Command+Left Arrow to return to the previous page.  Ctrl+Command+Right Arrow goes forward again.

Comment: Good info, @Matt. Feel free to edit that into the answer.

Comment: @MattHulse doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @JanacMeena I use this often and just tested again to be sure.  It works for me in 'OneNote for Mac' Version 16.26 (19060901) on MacOS Mojave.

Comment: My mistake, I had BetterTouchTool running and capturing that keystroke. Thanks again.